# setOnItemClickListener on ListView doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I don't now the problem with my conde but when I click as item on list view I cant change the activity.
I have a fragment "HomeFragment" the list view is in there, and I have a class that contains the adapter.

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String TAG ="HomeFragment";

        public HomeFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");
            final ListView mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_id);

            //CRIAR OS OBJETOS PARA OS PRODUTOS

            Produtos computador1 = new Produtos("ROG1", "ASUS", "523,52","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp);
            Produtos computador2 = new Produtos("ROG2", "ASUS", "853,52","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_carrinho);
            Produtos camara1 = new Produtos("nomecamara1", "lol", "133,82","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_carrinho);
            Produtos computador3 = new Produtos("Predator", "ACER", "942,37","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_carrinho);
            Produtos telemovel1 = new Produtos("IPhone7", "Apple", "723,25","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_comparar);
            Produtos telemovel2 = new Produtos("nokia2", "Nokia", "73,23","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_conta);
            Produtos computador4 = new Produtos("LEGION", "LeNovo", "1005,99","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp);
            Produtos telemovel3 = new Produtos("nokia5200", "NOKIA", "53,75","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_conta);
            Produtos telemovel4 = new Produtos("P20", "HAWAY", "723,52","drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_carrinho);


            //Adicionar os objetos dos produtos a um ARRAYLIST
            final ArrayList<Produtos> listaProdutos = new ArrayList<>();
            listaProdutos.add(computador1);
            listaProdutos.add(computador2);
            listaProdutos.add(camara1);
            listaProdutos.add(computador3);
            listaProdutos.add(telemovel1);
            listaProdutos.add(telemovel2);
            listaProdutos.add(computador4);
            listaProdutos.add(telemovel3);
            listaProdutos.add(telemovel4);

            //É PRECISO CRIAR UM ADAPTER PERSONALIZADO PORQUE A LIST VIEW VAI TER VARIOS TEXTVIEW POE COLUNA
            ProdutosListAdapter adapter = new ProdutosListAdapter(getActivity()
                    , R.layout.list_adapter_layout, listaProdutos);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), teste.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });


            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return view; //retorna o inflate do fragmento
        }

    }
```

And xml code of the list view items, maybe it helps to understand how the listview is displayd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img_prod1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="50" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_prod1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="textview1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_prod1_p2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="textview2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_prod1_p3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="textview3" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/title_mais_vendidos"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/message"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        </ListView>
        <include layout="@layout/activity_main"></include>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No, nothing happens

Comment: maybe `setOnItemClickListener ` isnt working at all. Can you paste the xml of the list?

Comment: I edit the post and put the xml

Comment: also please paste the `ListView`  xml

Comment: Also done below.

Comment: ImageButton is consuming the click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageButton` is consuming the click event.

Try to set `android:focusable="false"` on your `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_prod1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:focusable="false />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should finish current activity after startActivity() intent. So, add

> finish();

after startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter set onClickListener for every item, like this:

```
 public final static class ListItemViewHolder
        extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView categoryName;

    public ListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), teste.class);
             startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a private class for a custom click listener:

```
/**
 * Item click listener
 * */
private class FavoriteClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        FavoriteItem item = favoriteItems.get(position);

            Intent iIntent = new Intent(thisContext, DetailActivity.class);

            iIntent.putExtra("animal_id", item.getAnimalID());
            iIntent.putExtra("api_token", apiToken);
            iIntent.putExtra("is_logged_in", true);

            startActivityForResult(iIntent, ACTIVITY_PET_DETAIL);

    }
}
```

Then, in the onCreateView (or I usually do it down in onResume) I setup the ListView:

```
    mFavoriteList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_browse);

    mFavoriteList.setOnItemClickListener(new FavoriteClickListener());
```